# boost spirit: how to instruct the parser to read whole input and then report the result

Tags: c++, boost

I have a minimal example of an expression grammar (arithmetic expressions only) which should succeed only when the complete input is a valid arithmetic expression. It seems to me that parser is reporting success when even a subsequence results into the start symbol of the parser.

```
  template <typename Iterator>
    struct expparser : qi::grammar<Iterator, expression_ast(),ascii::space_type>
    {
        expparser() : expparser::base_type(aexp)
        {
            using qi::_val;
            using qi::_1;
            using qi::_2;
            using qi::_3;
            using qi::uint_;
            using qi::lit;
            using qi::alnum;


            aexp = tm >> +((lit("+") >> aexp))
                | (tm >> +(lit("-") >> aexp))
                | (tm >> +(lit("*") >> aexp))
                | (tm >> +(lit("/") >> aexp))
                | tm;

            tm = (uint_)[_val=_1];
        }

        qi::rule<Iterator, expression_ast(),ascii::space_type  >
        aexp,tm;
    };
}


int main()
{
     std::string input("3+5*}{%%");
//initial part is good but some junk at the end


 using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
         typedef client::expparser<std::string::const_iterator> parser;
         parser par; // Our grammar
         std::string::const_iterator beg = input.begin();
         std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();
//       std::cout<<"About to parse the expression "<<input;
         bool r = phrase_parse(beg, end, par, space, ast);
         if(!r)
         {
             BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(false,"NOt a valid expression to parse");
         }else
         {
             std::cout<<"Parsed successfully"<<std::endl;
         }
    }
```

When I run this program it succeeds because 3 matches with tm and gives aexp which is the initial symbol. How can we ensure the well formedness of the complete expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`phrase_parse` returns `true` if a match is found, even if that match doesn't encompass the whole string. It also modifies the front iterator it is given to point to the end of the match it found, which means that if the whole string is matched, the front iterator will be equal to the end iterator when `phrase_parse` is finished.

If you want to test whether a match was found and encompasses the whole string, use

```
     if(!r || beg != end)
     {
         BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(false,"NOt a valid expression to parse");
     }else
     {
         std::cout<<"Parsed successfully"<<std::endl;
     }
```